# Is there a function to quickly perform a nested loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, nested-loops

In my code I have a list1 of about length 12000 and a list2 of about length 2000, and I want to create data that is based on how data from both these interact and assign it to each value from list2 for each value in list1.

The idea of what I want is a nested dictionary that has this structure, but is created quickly:

```
dictionary =
{
    list1_val:
    {
        list2_val: value if condition involving list1_val and list2_val else other_value for list2_val in list2
    }
    for list1_val in list1
}
```

The only problem is that this action takes about 70 seconds in my program. I was wondering if numpy or pandas has a function that could do this efficiently, if there is a built in alternative, or if this is just straight up a bad idea.

How the line looks like in my code:

```py
def wordas2(wd, words, index, correct):
    global words2
    if index == 0:
        words2 = "".join("2" if wd[i] == words[i] else words[i] for i in range(5))
    if correct:
        words2 = words2[:words2.index(wd[index])] + "1" + words2[words2.index(wd[index]) + 1:]
    return words2

dictionary_expect = {wd: {words: "".join(["2" if wordas2(wd,words,index,False)[index] == "2"  else "1" if wd[index] in words2 and wordas2(wd,words,index,True) else "0" for index in range(5)]) for words in possible_wordse} for wd in allwords}
```

It looks messy, but what it is doing is that for each word in `allwords`, I make a dictionary with words from `possible_wordse` as keys and the value is the pattern wordle would produce if the word from `possible_wordse` was the answer, and the word from `allwords` was guessed.

The function wordas2 is just a way for me to change a variable inside of dictionary comprehension. It is needed because of the way wordle handles letters that are in the answer word based on how many times that letter appears.

#### Examples

`dictionary_expect["EERIE"]["CREPE"] = "10102"`

`dictionary_expect["EERIE"]["EERIE"] = "22222"`

`dictionary_expect["PIPES"]["GRUNT"] = "00000"`

If relevant, the lists in question both contain words of length 5.
The whole program is a **wordle solver**, so I create a dictionary that creates a dictionary for each guessable word, that has all the possible answer words as keys, and the pattern the guessword makes when entered if that answer word is the correct one.

I do this in order to calculate the entropy/expected information gained of each guessable word. I do this by summing up the chances of each pattern multiplied by log base 2 of 1/that chance for the possible patterns when entering a word. This then returns the expected amount of bits of information I get by entering that word.

**Python version 3.10.5, Numpy version 1.21.5, Pandas version 1.4.2**

Can certainly update any module if needed for quicker code.

Comment: `quickly` in the `numpy/pandas` world means using compiled methods to perform loops (in c code).  Python level loops are slower.  There isn't a faster way of setting the key/value pairs of a `dict`.  A `dict` is python class, meant to handle a general python objects as keys and values.  So there isn't a `numpy` like "faster".

Comment: What numpy method could I use as a replacement for the standard dictionary then? I tried to use dataframes instead, but I did not manage to find a numpy or pandas methods for creating a dataframe with data based on my two lists.

Comment: Another hinderance to doing the kind of faster `numpy` I describe is the `if/else` tests.  Those only work with scalars, single True/False values.  Even if you can generate an array of `np.array([True, False, False, True])`, you can' use that in an `if` test without a loop.